# Consistent read

Tags: mysql, sql

This is from MySQL docs(link provided below)

> **Note**
>   The snapshot of the database state applies to SELECT statements within a transaction, not necessarily to DML statements. If you insert or modify some rows and then commit that transaction, a DELETE or UPDATE statement issued from another concurrent REPEATABLE READ transaction could affect those just-committed rows, even though the session could not query them. If a transaction does update or delete rows committed by a different transaction, those changes do become visible to the current transaction. For example, you might encounter a situation like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(c1) FROM t1 WHERE c1 = 'xyz'; -- Returns 0: no rows match.

DELETE 
  FROM t1 
 WHERE c1 = 'xyz'; -- Deletes several rows recently committed by other transaction.

SELECT COUNT(c2) FROM t1 WHERE c2 = 'abc'; -- Returns 0: no rows match.
UPDATE t1 
   SET c2 = 'cba' 
 WHERE c2 = 'abc'; -- Affects 10 rows: another txn just 
                   -- committed 10 rows with 'abc' values.
SELECT COUNT(c2) 
  FROM t1 
  WHERE c2 = 'cba'; -- Returns 10: this txn can now see the rows it just
```

[Link to docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-consistent-read.html)

Could someone authoritatively answer on such question: in example above we could see that `SELECT` after `UPDATE` ables to see changes commited by different concurrent transaction. Looks like `UPDATE` statement freshes snapshot view for `SELECT` statement, right? Does it fresh whole snapshot view for subsequent `SELECT` statements or just fresh snapshot view of "t1" table?

Comment: This is the catch: `even though the session could not query them` Database connections is based on sessions and if a transaction is not closed yet the `select` within a session will not see changes on another session until it finishes.

Comment: @Jorge Campos Thanks for editing!